# In Visual Studio Code, is there any way to "Accept Combination" automatically?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code with Git.

I've noticed that whenever I have a merge conflict, and the "Accept Combination" resolution is available, it always does the correct and obvious thing.

Is there any way to just make it happen by default, so it doesn't even bother me with merge "conflicts" that can be resolved by "Accept Combination?"

Comment: Being able to accept the combination of two changes doesn't mean it is correct to do or will result in a (still) working application. It would need to accept the combination, compile the application, run your automated tests and even then - maybe the change is not yet covered by the automated tests? The responsibility would suddenly lie with VSCode and result in a lot of "community feedback" let's call it.

Comment: a conflict does NOT mean that a combination is ALWAYS the correct option, if 2 people change the same line most likely it is one of the other, YOU have decide

Comment: @PeterKrebs No, it wouldn't need to do any of those things. I only asked if there was a way to have it always resolve using "Accept Combination" if that option was available. Of course it might not be correct 100% of the time, but so what? Even conflict-free merges can produce a non-working program.

Comment: It sounds like the built-in [union merge driver](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#Documentation/gitattributes.txt-union) of gitattributes.

Comment: @ElpieKay That looks different; it seems to just accept all the lines from both branches. But maybe the key to getting VSC to do this, is to change the arguments it provides to the Git merge command?

Comment: Did you find any solution? I also want to merge another branch with 100+ files changed and automatically accept combination whenever possible, and do it automatically for all files.

Comment: @XCS No although I haven’t spent any time investigating it further.

Comment: @WillisBlackburn I looked further into the problem, and in my case I was doing a rebase, then whenever I merged a new commit, all the rebase conflicts would re-appear. I now switched to doing a basic merge instead of rebase, which solves the issue of having to re-apply all the commits and go again through all the changes.

Comment: +1. Each time I see "accept combination" I use it immediately. It's extremely useful, and whilst I'm aware of the potential downsides, after months of doing this I've never had any problems with this approach. For this reason I would really like to see a way to do this automatically. Perhaps this should be handled by Git's merge resolution rather than VS Code?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to just make it happen by default, so it doesn't even bother me with merge "conflicts" that can be resolved by "Accept Combination?"

Q1 2024: still no.

That "Accept Combination" option comes from [PR 173035](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/173035), for [VSCode 1.76.0, Feb. 2023](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/releases/tag/1.76.0).

But since then:

- Nothing in [VSCode issues](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Amicrosoft%2Fvscode+%22Accept+Combination%22&type=issues)
- Nothing in [`marketplace.visualstudio.com`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=%22Accept+Combination%22&target=VSCode&category=All+categories&sortBy=Relevance)

The closest to automating that process is [issue 165685](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/165685):

> #### Auto resolve conflicts when changes are equal

But that is not your use case.

Comment: Update: I just filed https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/205073

Comment: @OliverJosephAsh Good call. I will follow this issue with interest.

Answer (score 0):

The asker raised issue ticket https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/205073, where a maintainer confirmed that currently this doesn't exist, but they're open to have a command that auto-merges all changes that can be auto-merged that way.

There is a related command with ID `merge-conflict.accept.all-both` and name `Merge Conflict: Accept All Both`. Related source code starts [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/ba50d3b212caf4ed5504442493d1fd7b3e5dc140/extensions/merge-conflict/src/commandHandler.ts#L36). As for the feature you refer to in your question post, the source code for that is [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/ba50d3b212caf4ed5504442493d1fd7b3e5dc140/src/vs/workbench/contrib/mergeEditor/browser/view/conflictActions.ts#L94). But they're not the same thing.